# taking drawable name from database then access in R.drawable.name_database

Tags: android, database, android-listview

I'm populating a listView, I've 300+ images on my drawable folder & all the names are in database,
 so I want to populate those images by sorting on database so that I'll take that sort list in my listView,

but how can I can take those name one by one in here `(R.drawable.name_database)`

Or how can I get the image id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a `Context` instance. Here is an example to find `R.drawable.name_database`.

```
String name = "name_database"
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
return context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Iterate through lines 2-3 of that code snippet, for each name in the database.

Comment: in line 2 which Id I'm getting?
& in line 3 what I'm getting?

Comment: In line 2 , you get id of image int drawable named "name_database".

Comment: unfortunately, getIdentifier is not recommended to use anymore